# How can I diagnose / get more information about this Julia error?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, julia, stack-overflow

## Background

I'm trying to create a chemical equation of state solver in Julia. It utilizes multiple libraries, namely, `Optim.jl`, `BlackBoxOptim.jl`, and `Measurements.jl`. To my knowledge, the error I'm facing isn't completely caused by any of these libraries, but is related to them somehow. It doesn't completely crash the program either, *it correctly and completely solves both the `Optim.jl` and `BlackBoxOptim.jl` steps and doesn't formally report an exception aside from the terminal output*.

## What I want from this post

The project is rather large in terms of putting together a minimum working example, so I haven't included one (yet), but all I'm trying to do at this point is understand what this error means and what information I can take from it. Then I might be able to understand what is happening in my code.

Basically, **I'd like any and all information about what this Stack Overflow Error means**.

This error- to my knowledge -doesn't point to any line within my own project, but rather core Julia libraries.

## What I (might) know so far

Since there are a lot of `typeinfer` calls, my guess is that Julia is failing to understand something about a return type or input type in my code when the method is being compiled.

I've stuck `throw(Exception)` lines everywhere to try to narrow down a specific line within calculations or methods that might be responsible, to little avail, but have localized the issue to at least this chain of methods:

```
if typeof(p) <: Measurement
    p_uncertainty = p.err
    v_err = PRVolumeSolver.solve_volume_uncertainty(components, mole_fractions, kijmatrix, p_uncertainty, v_val, t)
else
    v_err = 0.
end
...

function solve_volume_uncertainty(components, mole_fractions, kijmatrix, p_uncertainty, v, t)
    target_function = create_volume_uncertainty_target(components, mole_fractions, kijmatrix, p_uncertainty, v, t)

    res = bboptimize(target_function; SearchRange=(0.0, 10.0), NumDimensions=1, Method=:de_rand_1_bin)  # todo set better range later
    return best_candidate(res)[1]
end
...
function create_volume_uncertainty_target(components, mole_fractions, kij_table, p_uncertainty_atm, volume_l_mol, t_k)
    target = function(volume_uncertainty_guess_l_mol)
        _t_k = t_k.val ± t_k.err
        volume = volume_l_mol ± volume_uncertainty_guess_l_mol[1]
        
        resulting_pressure = PengRobinsonState(components, mole_fractions, kij_table; t=_t_k, v=volume, minimal_calculations=true, using_measurements=true).pressure
        return (resulting_pressure.err - p_uncertainty_atm)^2
    end
    return target
end
```

## The error

The error is a Stack Overflow Error of some sort. It is tens of thousands of lines, but roughly follows this pattern:

It starts with this:

```
Internal error: encountered unexpected error in runtime:
StackOverflowError()
save_env at /cygdrive/c/buildbot/worker/package_win64/build/src\subtype.c:147
forall_exists_subtype at /cygdrive/c/buildbot/worker/package_win64/build/src\subtype.c:1448
```

Then this section repeats thousands of times

```
subtype_ccheck at /cygdrive/c/buildbot/worker/package_win64/build/src\subtype.c:521
var_lt at /cygdrive/c/buildbot/worker/package_win64/build/src\subtype.c:584
subtype at /cygdrive/c/buildbot/worker/package_win64/build/src\subtype.c:1256
subtype at /cygdrive/c/buildbot/worker/package_win64/build/src\subtype.c:1256
with_tvar at /cygdrive/c/buildbot/worker/package_win64/build/src\subtype.c:745
subtype_unionall at /cygdrive/c/buildbot/worker/package_win64/build/src\subtype.c:839 [inlined]
subtype at /cygdrive/c/buildbot/worker/package_win64/build/src\subtype.c:1285
exists_subtype at /cygdrive/c/buildbot/worker/package_win64/build/src\subtype.c:1426 [inlined]
forall_exists_subtype at /cygdrive/c/buildbot/worker/package_win64/build/src\subtype.c:1454
```

Later it switches to this (once):

```
subtype_ccheck at /cygdrive/c/buildbot/worker/package_win64/build/src\subtype.c:521
var_gt at /cygdrive/c/buildbot/worker/package_win64/build/src\subtype.c:623
subtype at /cygdrive/c/buildbot/worker/package_win64/build/src\subtype.c:1259
exists_subtype at /cygdrive/c/buildbot/worker/package_win64/build/src\subtype.c:1426 [inlined]
forall_exists_subtype at /cygdrive/c/buildbot/worker/package_win64/build/src\subtype.c:1454
subtype_in_env_ at /cygdrive/c/buildbot/worker/package_win64/build/src\subtype.c:1909
subtype_bounds_in_env at /cygdrive/c/buildbot/worker/package_win64/build/src\subtype.c:1919 [inlined]
subtype_in_env_existential at /cygdrive/c/buildbot/worker/package_win64/build/src\subtype.c:2235
intersect_invariant at /cygdrive/c/buildbot/worker/package_win64/build/src\subtype.c:2841
intersect at /cygdrive/c/buildbot/worker/package_win64/build/src\subtype.c:3121
intersect_unionall_ at /cygdrive/c/buildbot/worker/package_win64/build/src\subtype.c:2569
intersect_unionall at /cygdrive/c/buildbot/worker/package_win64/build/src\subtype.c:2614
intersect at /cygdrive/c/buildbot/worker/package_win64/build/src\subtype.c:3068
intersect_tuple at /cygdrive/c/buildbot/worker/package_win64/build/src\subtype.c:2717 [inlined]
intersect at /cygdrive/c/buildbot/worker/package_win64/build/src\subtype.c:3085
intersect_unionall_ at /cygdrive/c/buildbot/worker/package_win64/build/src\subtype.c:2565
intersect_unionall at /cygdrive/c/buildbot/worker/package_win64/build/src\subtype.c:2614
intersect at /cygdrive/c/buildbot/worker/package_win64/build/src\subtype.c:3071
intersect_unionall_ at /cygdrive/c/buildbot/worker/package_win64/build/src\subtype.c:2565
intersect_unionall at /cygdrive/c/buildbot/worker/package_win64/build/src\subtype.c:2614
intersect at /cygdrive/c/buildbot/worker/package_win64/build/src\subtype.c:3071
intersect_all at /cygdrive/c/buildbot/worker/package_win64/build/src\subtype.c:3166
jl_type_intersection_env_s at /cygdrive/c/buildbot/worker/package_win64/build/src\subtype.c:3412
jl_typemap_intersection_node_visitor at /cygdrive/c/buildbot/worker/package_win64/build/src\typemap.c:454
jl_typemap_intersection_visitor at /cygdrive/c/buildbot/worker/package_win64/build/src\typemap.c:621
jl_typemap_intersection_array_visitor at /cygdrive/c/buildbot/worker/package_win64/build/src\typemap.c:404
jl_typemap_intersection_visitor at /cygdrive/c/buildbot/worker/package_win64/build/src\typemap.c:607
jl_typemap_intersection_array_visitor at /cygdrive/c/buildbot/worker/package_win64/build/src\typemap.c:404
jl_typemap_intersection_visitor at /cygdrive/c/buildbot/worker/package_win64/build/src\typemap.c:583
jl_typemap_intersection_visitor at /cygdrive/c/buildbot/worker/package_win64/build/src\typemap.c:542
ml_matches at /cygdrive/c/buildbot/worker/package_win64/build/src\gf.c:2752
jl_matching_methods at /cygdrive/c/buildbot/worker/package_win64/build/src\gf.c:1885
_methods_by_ftype at .\reflection.jl:867 [inlined]
#findall#216 at .\compiler\methodtable.jl:57 [inlined]
findall##kw at .\compiler\methodtable.jl:54
jfptr_findallYY.YY.kw_9379.clone_1 at C:\Users\Will\AppData\Local\Programs\Julia-1.6.0\lib\julia\sys.dll (unknown line)
#218 at .\compiler\methodtable.jl:67
get! at .\iddict.jl:163 [inlined]
#findall#217 at .\compiler\methodtable.jl:66 [inlined]
findall##kw at .\compiler\methodtable.jl:65
jfptr_findallYY.YY.kw_9374.clone_1 at C:\Users\Will\AppData\Local\Programs\Julia-1.6.0\lib\julia\sys.dll (unknown line)
```

And then repeats this section:

```
abstract_call at .\compiler\abstractinterpretation.jl:1040
abstract_eval_statement at .\compiler\abstractinterpretation.jl:1167
typeinf_local at .\compiler\abstractinterpretation.jl:1462
typeinf_nocycle at .\compiler\abstractinterpretation.jl:1520
_typeinf at .\compiler\typeinfer.jl:214
typeinf at .\compiler\typeinfer.jl:209
typeinf_edge at .\compiler\typeinfer.jl:806
abstract_call_method at .\compiler\abstractinterpretation.jl:490
abstract_call_gf_by_type at .\compiler\abstractinterpretation.jl:143
abstract_call at .\compiler\abstractinterpretation.jl:1054
abstract_call at .\compiler\abstractinterpretation.jl:1040
abstract_eval_statement at .\compiler\abstractinterpretation.jl:1167
typeinf_local at .\compiler\abstractinterpretation.jl:1462
typeinf_nocycle at .\compiler\abstractinterpretation.jl:1520
_typeinf at .\compiler\typeinfer.jl:214
typeinf at .\compiler\typeinfer.jl:209
typeinf_edge at .\compiler\typeinfer.jl:806
```

Before finally ending with this:

```
_typeinf at .\compiler\typeinfer.jl:214
typeinf at .\compiler\typeinfer.jl:209
typeinf_ext at .\compiler\typeinfer.jl:892
typeinf_ext_toplevel at .\compiler\typeinfer.jl:925
typeinf_ext_toplevel at .\compiler\typeinfer.jl:921
jfptr_typeinf_ext_toplevel_10069.clone_1 at C:\Users\Will\AppData\Local\Programs\Julia-1.6.0\lib\julia\sys.dll (unknown line)
_jl_invoke at /cygdrive/c/buildbot/worker/package_win64/build/src\gf.c:2237 [inlined]
jl_apply_generic at /cygdrive/c/buildbot/worker/package_win64/build/src\gf.c:2419 [inlined]
jl_apply at /cygdrive/c/buildbot/worker/package_win64/build/src\julia.h:1703 [inlined]
jl_type_infer at /cygdrive/c/buildbot/worker/package_win64/build/src\gf.c:298
jl_generate_fptr at /cygdrive/c/buildbot/worker/package_win64/build/src\jitlayers.cpp:340
jl_compile_method_internal at /cygdrive/c/buildbot/worker/package_win64/build/src\gf.c:1970
jl_compile_method_internal at /cygdrive/c/buildbot/worker/package_win64/build/src\gf.c:1924 [inlined]
_jl_invoke at /cygdrive/c/buildbot/worker/package_win64/build/src\gf.c:2229 [inlined]
jl_apply_generic at /cygdrive/c/buildbot/worker/package_win64/build/src\gf.c:2419
#bboptimize#85 at C:\Users\Will\.julia\packages\BlackBoxOptim\ZdVko\src\bboptimize.jl:71
bboptimize##kw at C:\Users\Will\.julia\packages\BlackBoxOptim\ZdVko\src\bboptimize.jl:70
bboptimize##kw at C:\Users\Will\.julia\packages\BlackBoxOptim\ZdVko\src\bboptimize.jl:70
solve_volume_uncertainty at c:\git\julia-polymer-membranes\PolymerMembranes.jl\StaticPengRobinson.jl:266
#PengRobinsonState#1 at c:\git\julia-polymer-membranes\PolymerMembranes.jl\StaticPengRobinson.jl:90
Type##kw at c:\git\julia-polymer-membranes\PolymerMembranes.jl\StaticPengRobinson.jl:63
jl_apply at /cygdrive/c/buildbot/worker/package_win64/build/src\julia.h:1703 [inlined]
do_call at /cygdrive/c/buildbot/worker/package_win64/build/src\interpreter.c:115
eval_value at /cygdrive/c/buildbot/worker/package_win64/build/src\interpreter.c:204
eval_stmt_value at /cygdrive/c/buildbot/worker/package_win64/build/src\interpreter.c:155 [inlined]
eval_body at /cygdrive/c/buildbot/worker/package_win64/build/src\interpreter.c:575
jl_interpret_toplevel_thunk at /cygdrive/c/buildbot/worker/package_win64/build/src\interpreter.c:669
top-level scope at c:\git\julia-polymer-membranes\PolymerMembranes.jl\test.jl:29
jl_toplevel_eval_flex at /cygdrive/c/buildbot/worker/package_win64/build/src\toplevel.c:877
jl_toplevel_eval_flex at /cygdrive/c/buildbot/worker/package_win64/build/src\toplevel.c:825
jl_toplevel_eval at /cygdrive/c/buildbot/worker/package_win64/build/src\toplevel.c:886 [inlined]
jl_toplevel_eval_in at /cygdrive/c/buildbot/worker/package_win64/build/src\toplevel.c:929
eval at .\boot.jl:360 [inlined]
include_string at .\loading.jl:1094
include_string at .\loading.jl:1104
jl_apply at /cygdrive/c/buildbot/worker/package_win64/build/src\julia.h:1703 [inlined]
jl_f__call_latest at /cygdrive/c/buildbot/worker/package_win64/build/src\builtins.c:714
jl_apply at /cygdrive/c/buildbot/worker/package_win64/build/src\julia.h:1703 [inlined]
do_apply at /cygdrive/c/buildbot/worker/package_win64/build/src\builtins.c:670
#invokelatest#2 at .\essentials.jl:708
jl_apply at /cygdrive/c/buildbot/worker/package_win64/build/src\julia.h:1703 [inlined]
do_apply at /cygdrive/c/buildbot/worker/package_win64/build/src\builtins.c:670
invokelatest at .\essentials.jl:706
jl_apply at /cygdrive/c/buildbot/worker/package_win64/build/src\julia.h:1703 [inlined]
do_apply at /cygdrive/c/buildbot/worker/package_win64/build/src\builtins.c:670
#inlineeval#70 at c:\Users\Will\.vscode\extensions\julialang.language-julia-1.1.38\scripts\packages\VSCodeServer\src\eval.jl:193
inlineeval##kw at c:\Users\Will\.vscode\extensions\julialang.language-julia-1.1.38\scripts\packages\VSCodeServer\src\eval.jl:191 [inlined]
#65 at c:\Users\Will\.vscode\extensions\julialang.language-julia-1.1.38\scripts\packages\VSCodeServer\src\eval.jl:151
withpath at c:\Users\Will\.vscode\extensions\julialang.language-julia-1.1.38\scripts\packages\VSCodeServer\src\repl.jl:142
#64 at c:\Users\Will\.vscode\extensions\julialang.language-julia-1.1.38\scripts\packages\VSCodeServer\src\eval.jl:149
hideprompt at c:\Users\Will\.vscode\extensions\julialang.language-julia-1.1.38\scripts\packages\VSCodeServer\src\repl.jl:36
#63 at c:\Users\Will\.vscode\extensions\julialang.language-julia-1.1.38\scripts\packages\VSCodeServer\src\eval.jl:117
unknown function (ip: 0000000061063a51)
with_logstate at .\logging.jl:491
with_logger at .\logging.jl:603 [inlined]
#62 at c:\Users\Will\.vscode\extensions\julialang.language-julia-1.1.38\scripts\packages\VSCodeServer\src\eval.jl:183
unknown function (ip: 0000000061060a13)
jl_apply at /cygdrive/c/buildbot/worker/package_win64/build/src\julia.h:1703 [inlined]
jl_f__call_latest at /cygdrive/c/buildbot/worker/package_win64/build/src\builtins.c:714
#invokelatest#2 at .\essentials.jl:708 [inlined]
invokelatest at .\essentials.jl:706
jl_apply at /cygdrive/c/buildbot/worker/package_win64/build/src\julia.h:1703 [inlined]
do_apply at /cygdrive/c/buildbot/worker/package_win64/build/src\builtins.c:670
macro expansion at c:\Users\Will\.vscode\extensions\julialang.language-julia-1.1.38\scripts\packages\VSCodeServer\src\eval.jl:34 [inlined]
#60 at .\task.jl:406
unknown function (ip: 0000000061044b73)
jl_apply at /cygdrive/c/buildbot/worker/package_win64/build/src\julia.h:1703 [inlined]
start_task at /cygdrive/c/buildbot/worker/package_win64/build/src\task.c:839
```

Comment: I found this issue https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/39465 that also relates to stack overflow inside subtype and type inference in Julia itself. You may try the workaround suggested in the issue.